# Exercicio: transformar decimal para binario e encontrar 1's

Tags: c, algoritmo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int k,repeticao;
int valor, numero;
int paridade = 0;
scanf("%d", &repeticao);

for( k = 0; k < repeticao; k++ ){
    int numero,sequencia;
    scanf("%lld", &numero);
    valor = numero/2;
    while( valor != 0 ){
        sequencia = numero%2;
        if( sequencia == 1)
        {
            paridade++;
        }
        numero = valor;
        valor = numero/2;
        if (valor == 0)
    {
        paridade++;
    } 

    }

    printf("%d\n", paridade);
    paridade = 0;
}
return 0;

}
```

O meu código está funcionando para as duas entradas dada no exemplo: 3 e 21, mas na terceira entrada ele retorna 15, ao invés de 50.
essa terceira entrada é a repetição de 1 a 9 (3 vezes), sendo que quando eu repito ela duas vezes(123456789123456789)  a minha saída é 1( errado também) quando coloco apenas uma repetição(123456789) minha saida sai correta ( 16). Podem me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Você quer só contar os bits 1 de um inteiro? Acho que o código para fazer isso é bem mais simples. Basta fazer divisões sucessivas e contar quando houver resto.

Comment: Mas eu estou fazendo divisões sucessivas e quando o resto for 1 eu estou incrementando a variável "paridade". Deve existir um jeito mais simples, mas eu não conseguir enxergar, também gostaria de saber o motivo de não funcionar para todos os casos do jeito que está aí.

Comment: Vou postar minha solução.

Comment: Em Python seria muito fácil fazer isso porque as variáveis não tem tamanho definido, já em C acredito que não seja possível, nem o double suporta um número com tantos dígitos, o maior número suportado tem 16/17 dígitos já que é uma variável de 8 bytes. Assim não seria possível resolver esse caso.

Comment: @LuanPrado: Não diga "em C não é possível", não; é só fazer como Python faz e usar uma biblioteca de precisão arbitrária, como a [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) e a [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/). Aliás, [eis uma lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis uma solução simplificada e devidamente comentada para determinar o número de bits de um inteiro. Como se trata de um exercício e não de um problema prático. Recomendo que estude o código e entenda o seu funcionamento.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
//variavel que recebera o inteiro
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
//contador de bits setados como 1
int p = 0;

//enquanto a for maior que zero...
while (a > 0) {
    //verifica se a é impar
    if (a%2!=0) {
        p++;
    }
    //realiza divisões sucessivas 
    a = a/2;

}    

printf("Saída:%d",p);

}
```

**Atualização:**

O cálculo não funciona para o terceiro caso, pois o valor extrapola a capacidade de armazenamento do int, long, long long int....

> prog.cpp:7:32: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
>        unsigned long long int a = 123456789123456789123456789;

Comment: quando eu coloco a terceira entrada do exercicio ( 123456789123456789123456789) está com o mesmo erro que o meu codigo tinha: diz que são 15 ao invés de 50 bits  1

Comment: A sim, ocorre um overflow. Nesse caso o problema não está na sua solução e sim na capacidade de armazenamento do inteiro. Tenta utilizar long int.

Comment: se eu usar long int, qual flag eu devo usar?

Comment: vou adaptar a solução para calcular o número do enunciado.

Comment: Testei com unsigned long long int e esta retornando 35. Não estou conseguindo reproduzir esse calculo em algum lugar para confirmar se são 50 1s mesmo.

Comment: Achei muito estranho esse comportamento... mas de qualquer forma ,muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Será que quem propôs esse enunciado verificou a viabilidade de fazer isso em C? ... ou talvez há outra técnica que eu desconheço.